# Why is my Django serializer telling me an attribute doesn't exist when I see it defined in my model?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using Python 3.7 and the Django rest framework to serialize some models into JSOn data.  I have this

```
    data = {
    'articlestats': ArticleStatSerializer(articlestats, many=True).data,
```

and then I have defined the following serializers ...

```
class LabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = ['name']
...
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    label = LabelSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'path', 'url', 'label']

class ArticleStatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article = ArticleSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ArticleStat
        fields = ['id', 'article', 'score']
```

I have defined my Label model like so ...

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name",)
```

but I'm getting this error when Django processes my serialize line ...

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `LabelSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

Not sure why it's complaining.  The "name" attribute is right there.  What else should I be doing?

**Edit:** Models asked for ...

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleStatManager()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
    score = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False)



class Article(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleManager()
    title = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    path = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    url = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    label = models.TextField(default='', null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now)
```

Comment: can you add your `ArticleStat` and `Article` model?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, models are added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **`Article`** model the **`label`** field is **`TextField`**, not any kind of related fields. But in your serializer, it expects a related field.

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    label = LabelSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'path', 'url', 'label']
```